# Azure B2C Claims are not coming through

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Working through the example from MS site, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/

Once a user successfully signs in I cannot seem to get a hold of the claims set on the policy (in the Azure portal).

The claim object here is always null.

```
var type = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().NameClaimType;
var claim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(type);
```

I'm hoping I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

Do you check ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims? Those values are stored in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims. I want to check if you cant get values from the below code in Claims page.

```
@foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="claim-type claim-data">@claim.Type</td>
            <td class="claim-data">@claim.Value</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Hi, yes that list is empty as well.  After several days of trying to get things to work I have moved on to a different auth strategy.

Comment: Ok, I follow the sample from the document you provide https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet, I can get values form ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims, so the code has no problem, make sure the <appSettings> are properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The NameIdentifier doesn't exist in your claims identity.

Azure b2c doesn't provide this claim.

Answer (score 0):

You try the below code, it works perfectly fine.

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
```

### or

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "extension_ClientId")
```